# DateTime.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to assign the value coming from database into dataset and then to the DateTime in My code Can Anyone Fix my Code For That...

Comment: Please edit and add code, problem, error and what you have tried in order to solve your problem

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and as @GiladGreen mentions - please add more info:


https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add your code here man.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it out myself, you might want to consider something like this:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());
```

Please note that some defensive programming caution should be applied, such as making sure the data format in the row is valid.